# Fading text in and out using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to fadein some text 2 seconds after the page loads and after 5 seconds i want it to fade out. Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zbbv4z9n/)

I have tried using the following code:

```
<div id="intro-wrap">
<div id="intro-text">
        <h1 style="font-size: 20px; letter-spacing: 0.1em; font-family: serif; color: rgb(253, 236, 204); font-weight: 100;">Creating the world's most exceptional homes</h1>

</div>
</div>

$(window).on("load", function () {
$('#intro-wrap').fadeIn('4000', function () {
    // First Animation complete
    $(this).fadeOut('4000', function () {
        // Second Animation complete
    });
});
});
```

The issue is  the text quickly appears and disappears. How can I make it appear after sometime, make it visible for some time and then make it fade away?

Comment: Pass `4000` not `'4000'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setTimeoutI changed the color of the Text so you can better see the animation, this yellow stuff was just disgusting, sorry about that.

Fiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/zbbv4z9n/9/

You first need to hide your div to make it fadein otherwise it is already their.

```
     $(window).on("load", function () {
        $('#intro-wrap').hide();
        $('#intro-wrap').fadeIn(4000, function () {
            // First Animation complete
            setTimeout(function(){$('#intro-wrap').fadeOut(4000, function () {
                // Second Animation complete
            }); 
            },4000);// Wait for 4 Seconds before starting
        });
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use setTimeout function to hide that text after a particular delay time.
It will be something like:

```
$('#intro-wrap').fadeIn('4000', function () {
// First Animation complete
setTimeout(callFadeOut,5000);
```

});

```
function callFadeOut(){
$('#intro-wrap').fadeOut('4000', function () {
    // Second Animation complete
});
```

}

This will hide the div after a 5 seconds period

Answer (score 0):

First off, you should be using `4000` instead of `'4000'`

Secondly you can chain your functions together and use `delay` to wait a specified amount of time before moving to the next part. So your jQuery would look like:

```
$('#intro-wrap').fadeIn(4000, function () {
    //First animation complete
})
.delay(4000) //Wait 4 seconds
.fadeOut(4000, function () {
    // Second Animation complete
});
```

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p23p1bmj/) for a working version.

EDIT: Also note the `intro-wrap` div needs to be set to `display:none` for the `fadeIn` to work. (Assumed this is the case)

As per the OP, you can use `delay` anywhere in the chain, so if you want to wait 2 secs before fading in for 2 secs, waiting 5 secs before fading out in 2 secs, you can use something like below (change values to your needs):

```
$('#intro-wrap')
.delay(2000) //Wait 2 secs
.fadeIn(2000, function () {
    //First animation complete
})
.delay(5000) //Wait 5 seconds
.fadeOut(2000, function () {
    // Second Animation complete
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple issues here.

- First of all, your element that is going to fade in, needs initially be hidden.
- Second @Shaeldon is correct, fadeIn expects a numeric, not a string

**Code:**

I assumed here that you wanted to delay for 2 seconds, fade in for 4, delay for 5, and then fade out for 4. You can modify it if needed.

I also used [delay](http://api.jquery.com/delay/). Since you are including the JQuery library, you might as well use it.

```
<div id="intro-wrap" style='display:none;'>

$(window).load(function () {
    $('#intro-wrap')
        .delay(2000)
        .fadeIn(4000)
        .delay(5000)
        .fadeOut(4000);
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ascharp/zbbv4z9n/11/)